# Micro-USB connector in middle of PCB?

Tags: usb, pcb-design, connector, pcb-assembly

I have a unique situation where I may want to place a Micro-USB connector on a PCB, but not on the board edge. Mechanically, it would make sense if I could place it towards the middle of the board.

The concern is that the male end of the Micro-USB cable requires additional clearance on the top and bottom, which seems to prohibit this kind of connection as the PCB would be in the way of the bottom clearance:

[image: usb clearance]

I can't use a Right Angle (R/A) connector due to other mechanical constraints. 
I looked on Digikey and couldn't find anything that seems to fit.. Basically I want to take a regular Micro-USB SMT connector, and elevate it ~0.25" off the board.

One option I thought of is a breakout board like this:

[image: micro-usb front]
[image: micro-usb top]

Placed into a 0.100" female header on the board, like this (shown for representation, not the actual board):

[image: female header]

I think this could get the job done, but I'd much rather do something integrated to keep things streamlined, clean, and not require an additional assembly step. Open to any suggestions or recommendations.

Comment: Use a vertical part. Mouser Part #: 538-105133-0001

Comment: Or cut a hole in the board and feed a right-angle USB micro cable through it.

Comment: This isn't called "*I have a unique situation*",  this is called "*I've painted myself into a corner*".  Redesign the board such that you can put the connector on the edge.  [You wrote you're open to *any* suggestions.  So there.]

Comment: You don't need a female header on the main board - just solder the pins on the daughter board into the holes in the main board.

Comment: If you can't take the connector to the edge of the board, bring the edge of the board to the connector - @Daniel's suggestion of have a cut out by the connector is a good one if you can't add deep enough notch in the board outline. Just make sure the hole is wide and long enough to be able to mate the connector.

Comment: Actually, that might just solve it. Maybe i can cut a groove into the board and do it that way. Appreciate the suggestion guys.